# "SQLException: Data source is closed" when unit testing a Controller that calls a Spring-Batch job

Tags: multithreading, spring-mvc, concurrency, junit, spring-batch

I am getting the following exception when I run a JUnit test in which I test a Spring-MVC controller that calls a Spring-Batch job. The Job includes two tasklets: first read from a file & write to DB, then update the DB. Both tasklets use the same DB. As far as I can see, the exception tells me that the datasource is closed, but in the DB I see that the first tasklet has been executed, while the second one has not.

**Could you come up with any suggestion for why the datasource is closed (???) during the second tasklet (the update to the DB)?**

The job executes both tasklets when I call the controller from the browser.

```
ERROR [taskExecutor-1] (AbstractJob.java:306) - Encountered fatal error executing job
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:141)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=writeProductsJob at state=writeProductsJob.readWrite with exception
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:240)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy27.getStepExecutionCount(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.shouldStart(SimpleStepHandler.java:210)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:117)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1362)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:202)
    ... 18 more
Exception in thread "taskExecutor-1" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:240)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy27.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:329)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1362)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:202)
    ... 11 more
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.628 sec
```

**UPDATE:**

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class UploadFileValidatorTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockMultipartHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;

    @Autowired
    private MyController controller;

    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       request = new MockMultipartHttpServletRequest();
       response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    }

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void testDoSomething() throws Exception {

        DiskFileItem fileItem = null;

        final File TEST_FILE = applicationContext.getResource("classpath:csv_example.txt").getFile();

        try
        {
            fileItem = (DiskFileItem) new DiskFileItemFactory().createItem("fileData", "text/plain", true, TEST_FILE.getName());
            InputStream input =  new FileInputStream(TEST_FILE);
            OutputStream os = fileItem.getOutputStream();
            int ret = input.read();
            while ( ret != -1 )
            {
                os.write(ret);
                ret = input.read();
            }
            os.flush();
            System.out.println("diskFileItem.getString() = " + fileItem.getString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        request.addFile(multipartFile);

        request.addParameter("email", "email@email.com");

        request.setRequestURI("/book/upload.html");

        final ModelAndView mav = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter().handle(request, response, controller);

        BindingResult bindException = (BindingResult) mav.getModel().get(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "uploadFile");
        for (Object object : bindException.getAllErrors()) {
            if(object instanceof FieldError) {
                FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) object;

                assertEquals(fieldError.getField(), "fileData");

                System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage((FieldError) object, null));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Batch config:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor"/>
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
</bean>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I have tried to add the following code at the end of the `testDoSomething()` test method:

```
ThreadGroup threadGroup = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();

int activeCount = threadGroup.activeCount();

Thread[] list = new Thread[activeCount];

threadGroup.enumerate(list);

for (Thread thread : list) {
    if (thread.getName().startsWith("taskExecutor")) {
        System.out.println("WAITING FOR THREAD: " + thread.getName());
        try {
            thread.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
    }
}
```

Now the whole job is executed, but `testDoSomething()` never ends, it seems like it waits forever for the `taskExecutor` thread to die. Any idea why the `taskExecutor` never dies?

Comment: I can only guess that this tasklet runs in a separate thread while `main` thread is already stopping the application context, calling `BasicDataSource.close()`. Can you put a breakpoint on that method and see who is responsible for calling it? I bet it is the `ApplicationContext.close()`... Also, how does your integration test look like? How do you start the Spring context?

Comment: Please see **UPDATE** at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz - as you can see the job is defined to run in a different thread than the thread of the controller (and of the junit test). So I guess when the controller thread ends, junit closes all open resources (e.g. open data sources). How do I tell junit to wait with this closing of resources, until the job thread also ends?

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz - please see **UPDATE 2** at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: `taskExecutor` thread will never end because these threads are closed when the Spring context is shut down - and it can't be shut down because the test didn't finish yet (deadlock). As I mentioned I suspect the application context begins shutdown process while Spring batch job is still running. Can you somehow wait for it to finish? Also I bet that if you remove `destroy-method="close"` from your `dataSource` bean, it will work (but it is not a solution).

Comment: I don't understand some of your statements.. 1. "these threads are closed when the Spring context is shut down" - but while controller is invoked from browser, application context is alive while job thread dies after completing its tasks. 2. "Can you somehow wait for it to finish?" - yes, is it not what I did with `thread.join()`? the problem is that the tasks are executed but the job thread remains alive. Why is it so only when run from JUnit? **BTW** I tried to remove `destroy-method="close"` - result is, no exception due to closed datasource, but as before, last task in job is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem in my test.

The thing is that your batch job launching **asynchronously** and test finished but job is running(or about to run). And context already closed(and all beans closed too, including DataSource). So you need to use synchronous JobLauhcher in your test.
Example to define two launchers:

```
  <beans:bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">    
        <beans:property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jobLauncher_asynch"
          class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <beans:property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <beans:property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor"/>
    </beans:bean>
```